# retrieve particular properties from orienttb vertex

Tags: java, orientdb, orientdb2.2

I am trying to retrieve particular property of a vertex, say id. Is there a way to do it? I know the other way is to retrieve the entire vertex and then get the property i am interested. 
Note: I am trying to fetch from java.

```
graph.getRawGraph().command(new OCommandSQL("select from person").execute());
```

Then fetch id from each vertex,
However is it possible to do following?

```
graph.getRawGraph().command(new OCommandSQL("select id from person").execute());
```

Answer (score 0):

With OrientDB version 3.0.1 you can try something like this:

```
String statement = "select from person";
OResultSet rs = db.query(statement);
while(rs.hasNext())
{
    OResult row = rs.next();
    System.out.println(row.getProperty("id").toString() + " " + row.getProperty("name").toString());
}
rs.close();
```

this is the output:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Regards

Comment: i am doing the same way too, but wanted to know if i could avoid or better way to do it.